# Different prices in Shopping cart form and Shopping cart summary views in Commerce price table

Tags: views, commerce

I have a problem with price table module that I hope you can support me on this issue. As I have some products with different prices depending on item's quantity according to the commerce price table module, everything is ok except "Shopping cart summary view" that only show base price and don't show calculated prices according to quantities. Also I have found rule "Override price with price table" in admin>configuration>rules that it seems it doesn't any effect on "Shopping cart summary view" !! . If possible pls help me on this topic and thanks in advanced for your perfect module.

---

For ease of reference, pls find attached file that show the price difference in "Shopping cart form" with "Shopping cart summary".
[image]

Comment: In the shopping cart summary view, are you using the 
`(Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line item: Unit price (Price)` field to output the unit price?

Answer (score 0):

In the shopping cart summary view, are you using the 
`(Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line item: Unit price (Price)` field  or `(Products referenced by commerce_product) Commerce Product: Price (Price)` field to output the unit price?

You should be using `Commerce Line item: Unit price`, this one is overridden by the `Override price with price table` rule